# Find the max value of a function using AI

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm interested in learning machine learning but only if I know it's possible to find the max of an unknown function that get some numbers and return a number and for which a max exists.

Answer (score 0):

Very unspecific question and not exclusively related to machine learning and AI.

Let's say you have a "black-box"-function f(x1,x2,x,...,xn) which takes n input variables and returns a scalar value, but you don't know it exactly, **all you know is it has a maximum**.

What you can do is use so called [Evolution Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy) optimization techniques like [CMA-ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES). You basically sample random points x from a sampling function (e.g. gaussian), evaluate the points, rank them by their evaluation, adapt your sample function (e.g. by maximum likelihood of you k best points) and resample. After doing this over and over the mean of your gaussian will be a maximum (however not necessarily the global one!)

This however has nothing to do with machine learning or AI. In ML/AI you usually have points x and results y and you try to *find* the function f(x)=y that matches your points.